# constraint for varchar(5) field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, constraints

On sql 2008 having brain cramp.  Has a 3rd party app and db, has a phone extension field defined as `varchar(5)`.  Problem is they have a report (can't change) that errors out of anything other than a number is put in as value, and of course with `varchar(5)` they can put anything so report errors out.  Wanted to put a constraint to limit values up to 5 numbers including leading zeroes or null.  Struggling on syntax. This is what I have been doing so far

**Query**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.person_test2 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ext
    CHECK (Pext like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

which will not all nulls and has to be 5 characters.
What would be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 2):

```
CHECK (Pext Not like '%[^0-9]%' collate latin1_general_bin)
```

Is all you need.

There is no need to handle `NULL` specially. If the condition evaluates to unknown the constraint isn't violated.

The `^` negates the range specified so this condition evaluates to true for strings which do not contain a non numeric character.

You might need to add `AND Pext <> ''` if empty strings should be prohibited too.

The binary collate clause prevents characters such as `¼` matching. In many collations they sort between 0 and 9 and so would be included in the `0-9` range.

Comment: I have created a table with the constraint you propose and it allowed for the insertion of 'c1'.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I missed a trailing percent in the first edit (typing on mobile)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.person_test2 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ext
    CHECK (Pext like '[0-9]' OR
           Pext like '[0-9][0-9]' OR
           Pext like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR
           Pext like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR
           Pext like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
           )
```

This constraint allows `NULL` values and all numbers with any length between 1 and 5. Everything else is prohibited.

Edited after taking into consideration the correct remark from Martin Smiths answer.